# Can a templated Pointer class have a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I ran into a surprising revelation when implementing the pimpl idiom with a home made pointer class (I know: why roll your own? But bear with me). The following three files contain a minimal example:

Pointer.h:

```
#pragma once 

template <typename T>
class Pointer
{
public:
    Pointer(T*p=0)
        : _p(p)
    {
    }
    virtual ~Pointer()
    {
        delete _p;
    }
private:
    void operator=(const Pointer&);
    Pointer(const Pointer&);

private:
    T*_p;
};
```

Foo.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Pointer.h"

struct Foo
{
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

private:
    void operator=(const Foo&);
    Foo(const Foo&);

private:
    Pointer<struct FooPrivate> p;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Never mind what the innards of `Foo.cpp` look like. When I compile `main.cpp` with MSVC 2008, I get the warning:

```
pointer.h(13) : warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'FooPrivate'; no destructor called
```

The warning can be avoided by removing the keyword virtual from Pointers destructor.

This makes no sense to me. Is this warning legit, or is it a bug in the MSVC compiler? If so, can I safely ignore the warning?

I know it makes no sense in this case to make the destructor virtual, but remember, this is just a minimal compilable example. My original code is a lot more complex.

Comment: When you wrote *bear with me* I thought the reason for rolling your own smart-pointer would be presented later in your post. Sadly it wasn't. So, I feel compelled to ask - *Why*?

Comment: Have you looked into std::auto_ptr (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/) or Boost Smart pointers (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)?

Comment: The internals to `Foo.cpp` are quite important here... do you actually have an explicit `~Foo()`, or are you using the compiler provided one?  You don't have to do anything, an empty body is fine, so long as `FooPrivate` has been fully defined within `Foo.cpp` before you write it.

Comment: @Dennis: `~Foo()` is declared in the class definition. so it's user-defined (or not defined at all, in which case a link error should result some time later). The contents of `Foo.cpp` are irrelevant to the compilation of `main.cpp` since they are different translation units, and this is a compile-time rather than a link-time warning.

Comment: @Steve: I didn't actually mean to publish that comment, chosing instead to create a proper answer.  However, theoretically, the user defined destructor could have occured before the definition of `FooPrivate`... but since the warning goes away without `virtual`, that is almost certainly not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `virtual`, there is only one place the destructor is going to be called; within `~Foo`, at which point you have presumably fully defined `FooPrivate`.  If another instance of `Pointer<FooPrivate>` is created elsewhere, you might get the warning back, but since you don't the compiler can tell you're behaving safely.

With `virtual`, you can theoretically derive from `Pointer<FooPrivate>`, and that new object could be destroyed from somewhere that `FooPrivate` isn't fully defined.  The compiler isn't positive you don't do this, so it issues a warning.  You can safely ignore it in this trivial case, but if you have an actual need for a virtual destructor it might be a good idea to take it to heart.

Comment: What do you mean by second paragraph? Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: @Alf: Honestly, I am having trouble getting VS2010 to emit a warning about this under any circumstances, and I don't have access to VS2008.  The important thing is that verifying where a destructor might be called polymorphically is more difficult than verifying where a destructor might be called statically.  With a non-virtual destructor, all destruction has to be done statically.  Once a virtual destructor is introduced, the compiler is aparently chosing to err on the side of caution.  This may be a false positive under all circumstances, I'm not sure.

Comment: I have no trouble getting VS2010 to emit the warning (I'm not using any special options), and I still don't understand  your second paragraph. I suspect that it does not make sense for this code. A concrete example would be nice. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Since you are providing a destructor for class `Foo`, the warning appears to be completely incorrect & spurious.

Just to check that I added this code, in file [foo.cpp]:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct FooPrivate
{
    FooPrivate() { cout << "FooPrivate::<init>" << endl; }
    ~FooPrivate() { cout << "FooPrivate::<destroy>" << endl; }
};

Foo::Foo()
    : p( new FooPrivate )
{
    cout << "Foo::<init>" << endl;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    cout << "Foo::<destroy>" << endl;
}
```

Which yielded the same warning (with Visual C++ 10.0) as you got, but output

> FooPrivate::<init>
>   Foo::<init>
>   Foo::<destroy>
>   FooPrivate::<destroy>

Clearly, the executable is not doing what the sillywarning said it would…

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I realize now I should have posted the details of Foo.cpp. It looks exactly like yours. Note that it compiles without warnings. It is main.cpp that emits a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `delete` on an incompete type is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: How do you know it's incomplete at the site of the `Foo::~Foo`?

Comment: only if the destructor of the incomplete type, once it is completed, turns out to be non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't given a complete definition of `FooPrivate`, the compiler doesn't know what its vtable looks like. Since it can't call a virtual function that it can't locate, it bails.

Comment: Actually it doesn't bail. It just emits a spurious silly-warning. Then goes on to emit correct code...